# Sizing of viewbox content

Tags: xaml, windows-8, viewbox

I'm trying to get my head around using a viewbox container. I have a simple viewbox control and within it i have a simple button.

As expected this button is made the size of the veiwbox. How do i re-size the button to an acceptable size yet so it will grow when viewing on higher screen resolutions.

Comment: It seems like you'd have to size the ViewBox itself according to screen size, eg by putting it inside a Grid.  The ViewBox doesn't know anything about screen size.